# How to make Enter character forbidden in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i disable users to Not entering in TEXTAREA in html with javascript ?

Is it Possible to do it with Jquery ?

Comment: If you can't hit enter and go to the next line, why would you need a textarea and not just a regular input ?

Comment: You will need to put some JavaScript on the keydown and/or keypress, test if it's character code is 10, then suppress the default event action.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @CodeChimp - You meant lucky 13, right ?

Comment: Also, you have mis-tagged this as "java".  This is not a Java question, as Java and JavaScript are ultimately different things.

Comment: @adeneo Yeah, I always confuse those. My brain refuses to differentiate between 10 and 13 no matter how many times I have messed up and had to look it up again.

Comment: If you do not want to accept newline characters in your input, you need to enfore this on the server side. So why not filter the unwanted characters there?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(evt){
    if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VmfnL/).

Answer (score 0):

***This worked for me :***

```
 $('textarea').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
         e.target.blur();
 });
```

Hope, this helps

Answer (score 0):

Since you are preventing a key's value, the "keydown" event is the most appropriate. You don't need to juggle 13 and 10 in your head anymore, use [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property. The [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#value) is more intuitive than a number. As for actually preventing the key value, just `return false` which terminates the function.

```js
$("textarea").on("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") return false;
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```